# Electron app launched from start menu shell link alters process.execPath?

Tags: windows, electron

I'm using electron to develop an app. I'm using [`shell.writeShortcutLink()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellwriteshortcutlinkshortcutpath-operation-options-windows) to create a shell link shortcut in the start menu. I need the start menu shortcut to enable windows toast notifications. I also create a normal shortcut on the desktop.

For some reason when the app is launched with the shell link in the start menu my app's `process.execPath` is changed to `C:\Windows\System32` instead of the expected real location of the executable. The normal link works fine and `process.execPath` is correct.

This is a problem because I use `process.execPath` to access a file in the same folder as my app. Is this normal behavior for a shell link? Do apps launched with a shell link default their execution path to the System32 folder or is this something that is wrong with electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're not setting the cwd param of the ShortcutDetails passed to writeShortuctLink. If the working directory isn't set on a shortcut, the default is c:\windows\system32

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out right now. I don't know how I over looked that. I think I just assumed it would default to the path of the executable.

Comment: This was the problem. Actually my `process.execPath` was fine the whole time and it was entirely the cwd that was off. The cwd did default to System32 and that's where it tried to create the file.